# Android Studio Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner trying to lean android development, so I am taking google's android for beginner course, i have followed all the instructions but I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol price" in : displayMessage(createOrderSummary(price));

This is part of the code ...

```
/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int Price = calculatePrice();
    displayMessage(createOrderSummary(*price*));
        }


/**
 * Calculates the price of the order.
 *
 * @return total price
 */

public int calculatePrice() {
    return quantity * 5;
       }

/**
 *this method will create the order summary.
 *@param price of the order
 *@return text summary
*/

private String createOrderSummary (int price){
    String priceMessage = "Name: Ana";
    priceMessage +=  "\n Price;Quantity:" + quantity;
    priceMessage +=  "\nTotal $"+ price;
    priceMessage +=  "\n Thank You!";
    return priceMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int Price = calculatePrice();
    displayMessage(createOrderSummary(*price*));
}
```

With:

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int price = calculatePrice();
    displayMessage(createOrderSummary(price));
}
```

The crux of the issue appears to be that `price` shouldn't be placed between asterisks.

Also, whilst it isn't essential to swap `int Price` for `int price`, it is common convention in Android to make variable names (like `price`) lower case for their first character, and reserve upper-case first characters (i.e. `Price`) for class names.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a variable which does not exist.
Variable names should start with a lowercase letter, so instead of `Price`, use `price`:

```
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int price = calculatePrice();
    displayMessage(createOrderSummary(price));
}
```

Also note that Java is case-sensitive, so if you name something `price`, you can't refer to it by `Price`. The names of classes (types) should start with a capital letter though.

Comment: It's not a syntax error to name a variable starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I'll edit my comment to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for the explication !